# Циклическая отправка сообщений ботом ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте, бот

Я пишу бота для сообщества ВКонтакте. Вот код отправщика сообщения

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) { 
  return; 
} 

$confirmation_token = 'секретно))'; 

$token = 'секретно))'; 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

switch ($data->type) { 
  case 'confirmation': 
    echo $confirmation_token; 
    break; 

  case 'message_new': 
    $user_id = $data->object->user_id; 
    $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&v=5.62")); 

    $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name; 
    $last_name = $user_info->response[0]->last_name; 

    $body = $data->object->body;
    $otv = array(
    'Привет' =>'Elaon Bot - интеллектуальный FAQ бот команды ELTe Team' , 
    'Помощь' =>'Все доступные команды : О - отобразит всю информацию о боте' , 
    'О' => 'Версия бота - 1.2 Beta'
    );
    $message = $otv[$body];


    $request_params = array( 
      'message' => $message, 
      'user_id' => $user_id, 
      'access_token' => $token 
    ); 

    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 


file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 

    echo('ok'); 

break; 
} 
?>
```

Но когда я пишу сообществу сообщение то бот начинает отправлять один и тот же ответ бесконечно, вместо того чтобы отправить сообщение и молчать. В чем проблема. Уже не знаю куда копать (

Comment: может потому что $_REQUEST всегда существует

Comment: Хорошо бы показать код, который ВЫЗЫВАЕТ этот отправщик

Comment: rjhdby все в репозитории https://github.com/elaon/elaon_bot  ))

Answer (score 0):

При использовании CallBack api ВКонтакте сервер должен отвечать "Ok", если же на сервере произошла ошибка, то api ВКонтакте опять отправляет запрос на ваш сервер и так до тех пор, пока на все сообщения он не получит ответа "Ok"

Answer (score 0):

Советую echo ('ok'); делать сразу же. В принципе, для ВК не имеет значения, когда приходит ответ, и все действия после получения ok могут выполняться сообществом (ботом). Главное, что бы оно в принципе было. Добавляй сразу же после switch