# почему бот спамит? php vk

Tags: php, вконтакте

пользуюсь версией вк 5.103 
vk.com/dev/version

была проблема примерно тоже самая на: [Циклическая отправка сообщений ботом ВКонтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619132/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5)
но я отпровляю и 
    echo 
и 
    header(); 
    random_id 
использую: id 
    пользователя.rand(0. 100000000);
код на 
[Как правильно оформить код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048757/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня похожая проблема была связана с тем, что сервер VK не дожидался ответа от бота и отправлял повторный запрос. Короче говоря, скрипт бота выполнялся долго, и происходил таймаут.

Проверьте статистику запросов в VK, посмотрите на статус ответа от бота.

Если проблема в этом, возможно, вам стоит сначала отправлять "ok", закрывать соединение и потом уже выполнять код, который требует много времени.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема, бот в ответ отправлял одинаковые сообщения примерно каждые 5 сек. оказалось кода нормально не работал из-за того что на хостинге был установлен php 5.6 с переходом на 7.3 всё нормально заработало